# is <t extends comparable<t>> neccessary? can we use Comparable data type for all variables?

Tags: java, generics, interface, comparable

```
public class h{

   private int n;
   private Comparable[] harr;
```

and

```
public class h<T extends Comparable<T>>{

   private int n;
   private T[] harr;
```

what is the difference between the two and why and when is the latter preffered

Comment: Try to put an instance of the first, non-Comparable h into that harr array. What do you think will happen?

Comment: Why use `List<T>` if we could just use `List`?

Answer (score 1):

The latter provides type safety. WIth the former, any two objects that implement `Comparable` can be stored in `harr`, even if they are not comparable to one another (for example, `Integer` and `Charset`). This can lead to problems at run time. With the latter, such problems would be caught at compile time.